# How to load zip from storage in Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to open a .zip file that is inside the memory of the device, which contains some images that I want to show in a LazyColumn, the problem is that when I try to create a file by taking the path with the code that I will put below, I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: cl.test.test, PID: 8125 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1588070721, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.zip flg=0x1 }} to activity {cl.test.test/cl.test.test.MainActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File doesn't exist: /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.zip

I have a button that when clicked allows me to search for the file that I need inside the device:

```
@Composable
fun Content(paddingValues: PaddingValues){

    val fileSearch=
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
           openFile(it)
        }
    Button(onClick = { fileSearch.launch("*/*") }) {
        Text("Search file")
    }
}
```

Once the file is selected, I call the function "openFile":

```
fun openFile(uri: Uri?){
    val file = File(uri!!.path)
    ZipFile(file).use { zip ->
        zip.entries().asSequence().forEach { entry ->
            zip.getInputStream(entry).use { input ->
                File(entry.name).outputStream().use { output ->
                   //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when it gets to the line that says "ZipFile(file)" is when the error occurs.
I added the permissions for the storage also in the manifest file, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get a file path from the URI result. You can only read it with [ContentResolver.openInputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri))

So you can either :

- Copy the stream to a file somewhere in your app's internal storage or cache dir then create a `ZipFile`.
- Use a [ZipInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream).

Comment: I did just as you suggested and it worked, thank you very much :D